# dispatch an action in componentDidMount which receives a redux props as payload

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

What is the best way to trigger an action inside componentDidMount () using a redux props? ex:

```
import { fetchUser } from '../actions'
    class Example extends Component {
          ComponentDidMount(){
            this.props.fetchUser(this.props.id)
          } ... 

mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
   fetchUser: (payload) => dispatch(fetchUser(payload))
})

mapStateToProps = state => ({
 id: state.user.id
})
```

The problem is that ComponentDidMount () is mounted before the class even receives props from the store. That way my this.props.id is = 'undefined' inside the method.
One solution I found was to run as follows but I do not know if it's the best way:

```
    import { fetchUser } from '../actions'
        class Example extends Component {
     fetchUser = () => {
     this.props.fetchUser(this.props.id)
              }
render(){
  if(this.props.id !== undefined) this.fetchUser()
 } ...
}

    mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
       fetchUser: (payload) => dispatch(fetchUser(payload))
    })

    mapStateToProps = state => ({
     id: state.user.id
    })
```

That way I get the requisition, but I do not think it's the best way. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using async/await?

```
async ComponentDidMount(){
 await this.props.fetchUser(this.props.id)
} ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the lifecycle of react components. When the component gets mounted, it can fetch data, but your component at that point needs something to render. If the data hasn't been loaded yet, you should either return null to tell react that it's not rendering anything at that point, or perhaps a loading indicator to show that it's fetching data?

```
import { fetchUser } from '../actions'

class Example extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }
    render(){
        const { loading, error, user } = this.props;

        if (loading) {
            return <LoadingIndicator />;
        }

        if (error) {
            return <div>Oh noes, we have an error: {error}</div>;
        }

        // Render your component normally
        return <div>{user.name}</div>;
    }
}
```

Your reducer should have loading set to true by default, and when your fetch completes, set loading to false, and either set the user or error depending on if the fetch fails/completes.